# Get the required angle for projectile motion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I want to be able to figure out what angle the projectile should be fired from to hit a certain target which may not be at the same height as the cannon. Since the height is variable, I cant use the simpler equation of

```
dist = (v^2 * sin(2*theta)) / g
```

I need an equation for when the initial height is different.

I am trying to create a game (like pocket tanks) where the enemy AI will fire a pellet at you. but im not sure how to do the calculation to make that happen. so the AI would be aware of the height difference, the x-axis distance, the gravity and the initial velocity.

I saw the equation on wikipedia to find the distance given the angle, but i'm not sure how to rearrange the formula to get the angle given the distance.

I plugged the equation into wolframalpha and asked it to solve it for me, but I got like 10 different equations and im really confused on what I should do here other than just brute forcing it and sweeping through every angle until im able to get a hit.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Displacement) you will find the equation of projectile. If distance is d and height of target is h, then put x=d, y=h to solve for the angle.

Comment: @insipidintegrator I was not able to figure out which one you are talking about on the page. could you clarify?

Comment: The one with tan theta * x

Comment: that equation for displacement though. not for the range. So using that equation wont help for this situation will it?

Comment: That is the general equation which relates the height attained to the horizontal displacement at any point of time. $$y=\tan\theta\cdot  x-\dfrac{g}{2u_0^2\cos^2\theta}x^2$$